# "None" and "Any"

Tags: grammar, semantics, linguistics

Can anyone tell me more about the relationship between the words **none** and **any**

I'm specifically interested in their grammatical overlap, when they share a similar grammatical function in a sentence, and what that function is.

Also, any consideration of them, their relationship, or functional overlap in the fields of linguistics or semantics would be amazing.

And info about their etymology is also really useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh, boy; get ready to be amazed.

There is a **vast** amount of research on Negatives like *none*, and Negative Polarity Items like *any*.
Usually on [both together](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), since [NPIs](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf) require some negative context to be grammatical.

In particular, *none* is a negative **pronoun**
(for comparison, *no* is a negative **adjective**, and *not* is a negative **adverb**)

- *None of the men survived the earthquake.*
- *No man survived the earthquake.*
- *The men did not survive the earthquake.*

These are all forms of the same root, which starts with ***n-***, and [comes from Proto-Indo-European](http://web.archive.org/web/20080629221137/http://www.bartleby.com/61/roots/IE336.html).
As you can see, however, there is some complex syntax involved with these words.

As for *any*, it's the prototype Negative Polarity Item, which is only grammatical with a negative.

- *She didn't find any books.*  (grammatical; negative context)
- **She found any books.*  (ungrammatical; no negative)

It was thought for a long time that *some* and *any* were in complementary distribution;
*any* with negatives and *some* without. But this doesn't work, because questions:

- *Did you find any books?*
- *Did you find some books?*

It turns out that questions trigger NPIs, and *some* is perfectly OK in questions.
So there's much more going on.

For further information, consult the bibliography in the first link above.